# Copy products to all websites - Magento multi-store

Tags: php, mysql, magento, product

I am trying to copy my products from the first website I created to another 23 websites I added later in a multistore setup.
I have this code which I thought should do the job:

```
$arr_stores = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24);
$store_from = 1;  // first store id

// get observer data and process each imported simple product - my products that need to be copied to     other websites
    $_event = $observer->getEvent();
    $_adapter = $_event->getAdapter();

    foreach($_adapter->getNewSku() as $sku => $value) {

        if($value['type_id'] == 'simple'){
            // load the next product - this loads product correctly
            $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($store_from)->load($value['entity_id']);

                   // set the websites
            $_product->setWebsiteIds($arr_stores);
            $_product->save();

                    // clear the var
            unset($_product);

        }
    }
```

however I am getting this error message:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`workoutlife`.`catalog_product_website`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CATALOG_PRODUCT_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID_CORE_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `core_website` (`website_id`) ON DELET)
```

Can anyone tell me why this constraint may be failing?
And why is ON DELET there? I am not trying to delete anything.
TIA

Comment: did you find solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the core_website table. I'm guessing that one or more of the ids in the array are invalid (don't have a matching website_id in core_website). This would violate the constraint specified in the error.

The full constraint for the catalog_product_website table is:

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_CATALOG_PRODUCT_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID_CORE_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `core_website` (`website_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

ON DELETE CASCADE means that if you delete an entry from the core_website table, all the associated entries in the catalog_product_website table -- with the same website_id -- will be deleted as well. It's a way to ensure that there is no useless data leftover.

Nothing is being deleted in your example. MySQL just likes to show the whole constraint entry when it fails.

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens when the product can't be found e.g. there is no such ID/SKU or the parameter is NULL then the model returns new products object. Since that is empty model it requires you to fill it in with data like name, price, etc. But by the look of the code that is not want you want to do.

So the answer is first check that `$value['entity_id']` is actually set to something and is not NULL and second check that `$_product->getData()` or `$_product->getId()` is returning something if not that means the product can't be found.